# asp.net, adding the total of a group of list objects generated by a loop

Tags: asp.net, list, object

I'm working on a website where a customer can order items online.  When the customer clicks "Add To Cart", the order information gets stored in a list.  The list(order) information is displayed on a checkout page.  The prices are stored on the list but I'd like to total the prices generated by the loop, but I can't figure out how to do it. Can anyone shed some light on it?

```
public partial class ShoppingCart : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Product_Class> objList = (List<Product_Class>)Session["ObjList"];

        Label2.Text = " ";
        foreach (Product_Class prod1 in objList)
        {
            Label2.Text += String.Format("Product Name: {0}, {1} x {2}, Item Number: {3}, UPC Number: {4} <br />", prod1.ProdName, prod1.ProdPrice.ToString("C"), prod1.Quantity, prod1.ItemNumber, prod1.UPC);
            Label3.Text += prod1.ProdPrice * prod1.Quantity + "<br />";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the total prize of all items at the end just create a new variable and add the `inlineTotal` to the `totalPrizes`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Product_Class> objList = (List<Product_Class>)Session["ObjList"];

    Label2.Text = " ";
    var totalPrizes = 0;
    foreach (Product_Class prod1 in objList)
    {
        Label2.Text += String.Format("Product Name: {0}, {1} x {2}, Item Number: {3}, UPC Number: {4} <br />", prod1.ProdName, prod1.ProdPrice.ToString("C"), prod1.Quantity, prod1.ItemNumber, prod1.UPC);

        var inLineTotal = prod1.ProdPrice * prod1.Quantity;
        totalPrizes+= inLineTotal ;
        Label3.Text += inLineTotal  + "<br />";
    }

    Label4.Text = Strig.Format("Total {0}",totalPrizes.ToString());
}
```